# Как потокобезопасно использовать функционал библиотеки requests в Python 3?

Tags: python, многопоточность, requests

Допустимо ли вызывать

```
requests.get(url)
```

из разных тредов прямо так или нужно предусмотреть что-то ещё?

Comment: предусмотреть что? потокобезопасно это как? вы делаете `I/O` запрос, который ждет ответа от сервера

Comment: Потокобезопасно это как?
При вызове методов requests из разных тредов не произойдёт ли дедлок или иная неприятность?
Нужно получить от сервера много разных данных. Без многопоточности будет медленно.

Comment: ну почитали бы хоть)) дедлок может выскочить только если потоки держат блокировку другого потока. вы же просто по факту обычным циклом шлете запросы куда то там